# Angular 7 - JavaScript heap out of memory error

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular7

In Angular 7 application, When I execute ng serve command, it throws "JavaScript heap out of memory" error.

From different SO answers, I can understand that the issue is due to insufficient memory allocation to Node. As mentioned in their answers, by executing the below command I am able to compile/build the angular application.

```
node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve
```

But I need this memory allocation code written inside package.json or some configuration file so that I need not to execute the whole command each and every time. Also expecting, code logic should apply to all environments and should not create any issue during build in higher environments.

Can someone please help me to fix this. Below is my package.json code.

```
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
```

Comment: You can add NODE_OPTIONS ( URL - > https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360002046418-JavaScript-heap-out-of-memory ) environment variable but it will crash your VS application if it is lower than 2017 version.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First run This:

```
 npm install -g increase-memory-limit
```

Then add this line on your **package.json** file:

```
"myCustomMemoryComm ": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
```

**Like this:**

```
"scripts": {
            "ng": "ng",
            "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json",
            "build": "ng build",
            "test": "ng test",
            "lint": "ng lint",
            "e2e": "ng e2e",
            "myCustomMemoryComm": "node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"
          },
```

Then your further command will be every time for **running the project** (serve):

```
npm run myCustomMemoryComm -serve
```

Or Direct Run this on console:

```
 node --max_old_space_size=8000 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
```

And For **Production build**:

```
  node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --baseHref=/your-project-name/ --prod=true
```

Comment: I'm afraid if it cause any error during prod build through azure devops since we may not able to execute the first command during prod build. I want to execute the same ng serve or ng build in terminal. Is it possible to modify the package.json file accordingly.